# PyCharm cant use scrapy even after being installed using Anaconda

Tags: python, scrapy, pycharm, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda and downloaded Scrapy through it. Now when I want to start a new Scrapy project using Pycharm, it says that

> Scrapy is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

What should I do?

Comment: Usually, it happens because the variable is absent in the system "Environment variables". I have my scrapy.exe file in C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts, please check yours.

Comment: You have to check in which conda environment you have installed scrapy and select that environment when creating your PyCharm project. Or create a new one and install scrapy in your new environment (from the terminal of PyCharm, for example).

Comment: When I install directly through PyCharm, Error is shows which asks for Microsoft visual studio installation. I have tried installing the visual studio but still cant download. That is why I chose the Anacona route.

Comment: Are you using the correct Python installation in pycharm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's a virtual environment problem ...

First, it should be clarified that Anaconda uses a virtual environment system similar to `pyenv` or `virtualenv`: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39928067/3025562) to know more.

By default, Anaconda has a "base" environment, which is the one I assume you have installed `scrapy` on.

*You can [create new environments](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) with:*

```
conda create -n <env_name> python=<version>
```

Having clarified this, you have to take into account that what is installed in an environment is only available in that environment.

When creating a new project in PyCharm, it creates a new environment by default (with `virtualenv`, `pipenv`, or whatever depending on how it is configured by default).

If you want to use a conda environment you must [add it to PyCharm](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/pycharm/#configuring-a-conda-environment-in-pycharm) and select it as an interpreter in your PyCharm project.

Then, what you install in that environment ...

```
conda install -c conda-forge scrapy
pip install scrapy
```

... will be available in the terminal and / or the python interpreter from PyCharm.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. This has solved my query. The first command doesnt solve it, but the "pip install scrapy" downloads everything properly in the venv and now it works like smoothy

Comment: Nice! The second command install the scrapy binary, while the first one install the scrapy python library which let you `import scrapy`.

Comment: @user3769820 Be very careful when using pip inside of a Conda environment, see https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment.