# What is difference between using and not using Python to run the venv command?

Tags: python

I'm making a concerted effort to understand how Python packaging works and I keep seeing the following idiom being used over and over.  For example, if you're using venv to create a virtual environment, you can do this...

```
python3 -m venv tutorial_env
```

or you can do this

```
pyvenv tutorial_env
```

Under the hood, what is the real difference between using python3 to create the virtual environment and using pyvenv to create it?  Why would you use one command rather than the other?

Comment: I guess this could help: [difference-between-venv-pyvenv-pyenv-virtualenv-virtualenvwrappe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573587/what-is-the-difference-between-venv-pyvenv-pyenv-virtualenv-virtualenvwrappe)

Comment: Thanks.  Your link lead me to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950300/what-is-the-relationship-between-virtualenv-and-pyenv which says that pyvenv is a wrapper around venv that was deprecated in Python 3.6.  This link https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.6.html#id8 tells why pyvenv was deprecated.

Comment: you can write the answer to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [python docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.6.html#id8) both are equivalent.
Here is the [pvenv script](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.4/Tools/scripts/pyvenv) from [python 3.4 source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.4):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    rc = 1
    try:
        import venv
        venv.main()
        rc = 0
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error: %s' % e, file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(rc)
```

Note:

> The `pyvenv` script shipped with Python 3 but has been deprecated in
>   Python 3.6+ in favour of `python3 -m venv`. This prevents confusion as
>   to what Python interpreter pyvenv is connected to and thus what Python
>   interpreter will be used by the virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

Mayank Porwal's answer lead me to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950300/what-is-the-relationship-between-virtualenv-and-pyenv) which says that pyvenv is a wrapper around venv that was deprecated in Python 3.6.

This [What's New in Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.6.html#id8) tells why pyvenv was deprecated.