# org-babel python environment setup

Tags: python, emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I've tried to setup a python virtual environment following the top answer here:
https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24267/using-org-babel-to-enable-virtualenv/38047
I tried activating the virtual environment using two methods: `source $PYENV/bin/activate` and `pyvenv-workon $PYENV`. I expect to see the output of `which python` and `which pip` refer back to this virtual environment, but it uses the computer's primary python installation. The path to `$VIRTUAL_ENV` is correct, however. Similarly, the final code block does not use the virtual environment as expected either. Any ideas what I'm missing?

```
    #+BEGIN_SRC bash :dir ~/ :results drawer   
pwd   
python3 -m venv py3_venv 
    #+END_SRC

    #+RESULTS: 
:RESULTS: 
/home/jj 
:END:

    #+BEGIN_SRC bash :dir ~/ :results raw drawer 
source py3_venv/bin/activate
    #+END_SRC

    #+RESULTS: 
:RESULTS: 
:END:

    https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24267/using-org-babel-to-enable-virtualenv/38047
    #+BEGIN_SRC elisp :session venv-py3 :results raw drawer 
(pyvenv-workon "py3_venv")
    #+END_SRC

    #+RESULTS: 
:RESULTS: nil 
:END:

    #+BEGIN_SRC sh :session venv-py3 
echo $VIRTUAL_ENV 
echo $PYTHONPATH 
which python 
which pip
    #+END_SRC

    #+RESULTS: 
| /home/jj/.virtualenvs/py3_venv 
| 
|                                
| 
| /home/jj/anaconda3/bin/python  
| 
| /home/jj/anaconda3/bin/pip     |

    #+BEGIN_SRC python :results output :session venv-py3 
import sys \
print('\n'.join(sys.path))
    #+END_SRC

        #+RESULTS: 
: /home/jj/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip 
: /home/jj/anaconda3/lib/python3.7 
: /home/jj/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload 
: /home/jj/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

Comment: Have you tried [setting org-babel-python-command](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/28186/8811) to the desired python executable in your `.emacs` file?

Comment: [`venv` is a builtin implementation of `virtualenv`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29950604/190597) and the [user guide for `virtualenv` states](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/), "If you directly run a script or the python interpreter from the virtualenv’s bin/ directory (e.g. path/to/ENV/bin/pip or /path/to/ENV/bin/python-script.py) then **sys.path will automatically be set to use the Python libraries associated with the virtualenv**" (my emphasis). So merely setting `org-babel-python-command` is enough to essentially activate that venv. (See the caveat in the above link.)

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: Can one set `org-babel-python-command` for a single org-babel block using some keyword or something?